# Two points in a charged hollow sphere with zero potential difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Two concentric spheres (I've provided a simple sketch below) with radii $a$ and $b$ are given. The space between two spheres (colored yellow) is charged homogeneously, meaning that the charge density per unit of volume, $\rho$ , is a constant. The task is to calculate the voltage between points $A$ and $B$.

[image]

First, we notice that electric field vector, $\vec{E}$ (marked with red vectors), spreads radially throughout the space. The voltage between points $A$ and $B$ is calculated using the formula:

$$U_{AB}\int_A ^B {\vec{E}\cdot {d\vec{l}}}$$

It can be concluded that the voltage between points $A$ and $A'$ is zero, so the solution to our problem is going to be the voltage between $A'$ and $B$. But why is this so?

My explanations for this would be as following:

We know that voltage does not depend on the path of integration. If we try to apply the integral formula after choosing the straight line $\overline{AA'}$ as the path, we can conclude that $\vec{E}=0$, because we have no charge in the hollow space, thus no electric field. Also, from the sketch above, we can clearly see that $\vec{E}$ starts at the distance $a$ from the center of the spheres and spreads radially.

If $\vec{E}=0$, then $\int_A ^{A'} {\vec{E}\cdot {d\vec{l}}} = 0$.

If for the path of integration we choose the shortest semi-circular line connecting $A$ and $A'$, in every infinitesimally small part of that line, $dl$ (dashed brown line), vector $\vec{E}$ is perpendicular to $d\vec{l}$, so we get

$\int_A ^{A'} {\vec{E}\cdot {d\vec{l}}} =$
$\int_A ^{A'} {E \cdot dl \cdot \cos\measuredangle (\vec{E}, d\vec{l})}=$
$\int_A ^{A'} {E \cdot dl \cdot \cos{90°}}$

and $\cos{90°}=0$, so the voltage is zero.

As I said above, the voltage between two points does not depend on the chosen path of integration, so if I choose one path and prove the voltage is zero, it will always be equal to zero.

What interests me is the following: which line of reasoning is correct? Did I get something wrong? Which way of thinking should I apply for problems similar to this?

If there is anything I need to clarify, please let me know so I can explain myself better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note - you stated "we have no charge in the hollow space, thus no electric field". That is **only** true because the charge outside your space is spherically symmetrical!

Comment: @Floris I am aware of this, so my next sentence was: "Also, from the sketch above, we can clearly see that E starts at the distance a from the center of the spheres and spreads radially ". If we had a decentralized hollow sphere, we would have electric field inside it. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a difference between the two lines of reasoning.  In each case you are taking a path integral along a chosen path and calculating all of the contributions of $\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$.  You could choose an arbitrary path, and this would still be the case, but the integral would be more complicated.

An easy way to think about this is to use Gauss' Law with the spherical symmetry of your system.  A Gaussian surface (sphere) inside of the shell will enclose no charge, and due to symmetry, you can argue that $\vec{E}$ is zero everywhere inside the sphere, **including the inner surface**.  Since, $\vec{E}$ is zero, there is no way to contribute to the integral $\int_A^{A'}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$ for any path inside of the sphere, so the voltage difference between $A$ and $A'$ is zero.